# Rounding Floats

Tags: python

So I have a simple equation that rounds a number that is imported into the function as a float. Just incase the number imported is say `53.3` it should still recognize it as an "integer" but it wasn't when I didn't set it as a float and I set it as integer because there is a "."

Any ideas?

```
def cm(centimeter):
    result = round(centimeter / 100, 2)
    print ("%d centimeters is the same as %d meters." % (centimeter, result))
    print (result)

cent=input("Centimeters: ")
cm(float(cent))
```

The problem is that this is what it outputs:

```
Centimeters: 53.6
53 centimeters is the same as 0 meters.
0.54
```

It should look like this:

```
Centimeters: 53.6
53.6 centimeters is the same as 0.54 meters.
```

Took out print(result), my bad. It still rounds it to 0 meters though when it shouldn't seeing on how result outputs as 0.54.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your `print` function.

You want to say:

`print ("%.2f centimeters is the same as %.2f meters." % (centimeter, result))`

`%d` formats the variable as an integer; `%f` formats it as a floating-point number. The `.2` sets the precision: the number of decimal places it displays till.

Comment: I don't know if he should have `%.2f` at the start.  Shouldn't it be `%s` so that it shows the whole input, not a rounded version?

Comment: Honestly, that's entirely up to him; I'd probably want to round it off after around 2 decimal places.

`%s` would work though, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Make your function like this:

```
def cm(centimeter):
    result = round(centimeter / 100, 2)
    print ("%s centimeters is the same as %.2f meters." % (centimeter, result))
```

demo:

```
Centimeters: 53.6
53.6 centimeters is the same as 0.54 meters.
```

Also, note that I chose to use `%s` at the start instead of `%.2f`.  This is so the output will display the *whole* input, not a rounded version.  Meaning, if the user enters something like `53.006`, it will show `53.006` and not `53.01`.